# I can't access my prestashop admin page?

Tags: content-management-system, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

### I can't access my prestashop admin page (in localhost)?

When I enter into this page, it's shows this error!

How to fix this problem? Please help me.

[image: Server error 500]

Answer (score 1):

Prestashop changes its admin folder to something like admin12fsg7wghdfgf. You need to go to folder where you installed prestashop and find that folder. And after that you could enter backend side by link similar to this http://localhost/prestashop/adminwt3452sdg

Comment: Thank You Problem solved, but your tips doesn't work .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I even deactivate the antivirus and nothing fixed the problem.
Then what I did is to install the eCommerce in a Cpanel and over there all worked perfectly.

It's caused perhaps because Prestashop is tracking urls for his product's installations and of course this doesn't work in localhost...

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem and it became alright after I downgraded the PHP version to the one recommended by Prestashop for the relevant version. 
In my case, the PHP version was 7.2 and Prestashop 1.6. The admin page did not open, 500 Error.
I lowered the PHP version to 5.6. May be upto 7.0 it accepts.